# Freeing RAM In Tkinter(Python 3.6)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

what's up?
So, I'm currently working on a school project, and I'm using tkinter in order to display images onto a canvas (using a pmw scrolledcanvas in case that matters) and after I'm 'deleting' the images they still stay in memory.

```
        def f():
            self.canv.component('canvas').delete(ALL)
            self.plslabel.configure(text=self.plsts.name.upper())
            self.plslabel.place(x=617, y=45, anchor=CENTER)
            songs = [song for song in self.plsts.songs]
            print("REFRENCE COUNT IS ",sys.getrefcount(self.canv.image))
            del self.canv.image[:]
            del self.canv.image
            gc.collect()
            self.canv.image = []
```

The program is music themed so that's why the naming is like it is
so.. if I try to display a playlist on the screen (a set of songs) and afterwards I'm displaying another one the RAM bumps up, until it can even reach GB realms which is really not good.
It starts at around ~80mb(ok considering there's other stuff) and ends like this after an hour of using it and displaying and discarding playlists.

[image: Final Ram]

So what I'm asking is if there's a way to free up the ram comsumed by those images, or if it's maybe something else I'm missing, I tried using the garbage collector and going thorugh online solutions but it didn't seem to work so if anyone can help me please help :)

I put some effort into it and here's a small example, I think the issue comes from the threading implementation, make sure to ignore the errors.

```
import tkinter, sys, gc
import requests
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import CENTER, ALL, Label
from threading import Thread


def make_image(imageobj, x, y, myCanvas):
    photo = imageobj
    myCanvas.image.append(photo)
    myCanvas.create_image(x, y, image=photo, anchor="nw")

class Gui:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.resizable(True, True)
        self.canv = tkinter.Canvas(self.root)
        self.canv.image = []
        self.canv.pack()
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.root,text="Click me to consume RAM!",command=self.run)
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.after(5,self.run)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            def f():
                self.canv.delete(ALL)
                print("REFRENCE COUNT IS ",sys.getrefcount(self.canv.image))
                del self.canv.image[:]
                del self.canv.image
                gc.collect()
                self.canv.image = []
                print("REFRENCE COUNT 2 IS ",sys.getrefcount(self.canv.image))
                img = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get('https://image.prntscr.com/image/k0ZiVsRsQK6h2XbQtzRCUA.png').content))
                image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
                make_image(image,0,0,self.canv)
            t = Thread(target=f)
            t.start()


root2 = tkinter.Tk()

Appwindow = Gui(root2)
root2.mainloop
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example? Right now we can't run your code and debug it.

Comment: sorry about the fact that's it dirty, it took me a little while to simplify the issue, thanks for showing interest!
considering the fact that I have to view way more than a single image and that the images are larger in size then the one I provided I see the issue, but I just cant track why it happens

Comment: Let me just say that threading is not required

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that, thing is It'll make my software slower if I wont use it
And regardless, it shouldn't really make a difference as long as I delete the image object and all of it's contents using del and then collected the garbage, it should free the memory so what went wrong:(

Comment: You are deleting the self.canv.image, then you make it an empty list.

Comment: yeah, so new image objects created could be placed there, what's wrong?
it should still delete the old one contaning the image object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216225/discussion-between-themaker-and-idan-b).